# fav-icon doesn't change even after deleting the file and clearing cache and data

Tags: html, css

I want to change or delete fav icon from my pure html/css webpage but; no matter what I do, I see no changes. here's the steps I passed and the results are metioned too:

**Step 1**
I set .     as expected, the fav icon showed up. but then I wanted to delete the fav icon or maybe change it.
[image: [Image of step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9lw8.png)]

**Step 2**
I deleted the tag  mentioned above, but it didn't changed. I also deleted the file from the directory, again no change. I even cleared the cache and data from the consule and setting, but agian no change!
even in incognito mode still there's that fav icon on page, though there's no code or file to read from.
[image: [Image of step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZDcv.png)]

Please help me to find the thing I've missed here for solving the problem.
in advance, thanks for your time.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

This issue may be caused by browser cache, and sometimes it even occurs in incognito mode. If you open the 'training.html' file in a different browser than the one you have previously used, you will notice that there is no favicon anymore

Comment: Thanks, Sahand for your response.
It almost worked, on firefox everything is fine, once I comment the fav-icon code line it disappears. but on Chrome, it's still there.

I found another way to solve this problem on Chrome, which also helped me more than that. The extension "live server" helped me to synchronize the saved code and the website running on the browser. this also fixed the fav-icon problem with Chrome.

But still, without it, chrome never changes the fav-icon.

Answer (score 2):

I found a workaround for this problem. In advance, I gotta say that on Firefox everything is fine, once I comment the fav-icon code line it disappears. but on Chrome, it's still there. I found another way to solve this problem on Chrome, which also helped me more than that. The extension "live server" helped me to synchronize the saved code and the website running on the browser. this also fixed the fav-icon problem with Chrome. But still, without it, chrome never changes the fav-icon.